# Green squares on second monitor?

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors

I'll try to be as succinct as possible:

### Setup:

GPU: GeForce GTX 980 Ti, latest drivers

2 monitors, main connected via HDMI, secondary connected via DP

Windows 10, build 19041.153

### Problem:

Second monitor shows "faulty green squares" in some images; it's not the whole screen, but mostly along the lines where certain subtle color contrast happens. For instance, in that Windows 10 wallpaper with the red-ish hills (I think it's flowers?), I only see the green squares at the top-right of the image, in a line like a contour of the top-right deep-purple color. Almost like framing it.

Interestingly enough, **whenever I unplug and plug back in, the problem goes away... Until next reboot!**

### Steps to reproduce:

Almost every time I reboot (but not always) I get these. And not only in the wallpaper image, but in some pictures too. Not all of them, not even most of them. If I unplug and plug, the problem goes away... Until next reboot... Perhaps.

I've changed the GPU plug I use, formatted/clean installed Windows (not for this particular reason though, but problem persisted), changes resolution/frequency/color settings. Still the same. I happened to notice this bug after installing the latest Windows 10 preview build though, so that MIGHT have something to do with it. At the same time, I installed Windows 10 using GPT on a new SSD, so that could have something to do too. Of course I had to open up the PC to do the above, so that's another variable.

What do you guys think?

Comment: GPU or its drivers. Try an earlier driver, e.g., the Studio drivers, designed for maximum stability.

Comment: Did you try to replace the cable?

Comment: @spike_66, unfortunately I don't have another cable, but I really doubt that's the case

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit! f.lux was being loaded at startup, and for whatever reason the latest version was clashing with latest NVIDIA drivers. Uninstall either and things work dandy! (I chose f.lux of course)